# Managing multiple windows on multiple monitors

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-monitors

I have an application that can launch several windows upon clicking.

In a dual monitor system, if I drag over the main wondow to a second screen in extended mode, and then launch a child window, it(the child ) always comes in the main monitor.

How can I force the child window to always **appear in the same screen/ monitor as its parent?**

The applciation is in Qt and C++.

Kindly help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html#use-of-the-primary-screen

You can probably change the primary screen for your application depending on where the main widget is located if you're using multiple desktops. If you're using a virtual desktop, you probably can get the geometry of all screens, infer where your main widget is and change the initial position of  the other widget depending on that to ensure they're all on the same screen.

Comment: Ah, I couldn't get you clearly. Could you develop on your point, please? Especially regarding the multiple monitor part. How and where would I use it?